# Catch exception in node during JSON.parse

Tags: json, node.js, parsing, exception

My node server dies when it is unable to parse JSON in the following line:

```
var json = JSON.parse(message);
```

I read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310521/node-js-best-practice-exception-handling) on how to catch exceptions in node, but I am still not sure what is the proper way to wrap a try and catch block around this statement. My goal is to catch the exception and log an error to the console, and of course keep the server alive. Thank you.

Comment: Can you show this in context?  What is calling this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [proper way to catch exception from javascript method JSON.parse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467044/proper-way-to-catch-exception-from-javascript-method-json-parse)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

It's all good! :-)

`JSON.parse` runs synchronous and does not know anything about an `err` parameter as is often used in Node.js. Hence, you have very simple behavior: If JSON parsing is fine, `JSON.parse` returns an object; if not, it throws an exception that you can catch with `try / catch`, just like this:

```
webSocket.on('message', function (message) {
  var messageObject;

  try {
    messageObject = JSON.parse(message);
  } catch (e) {
    return console.error(e);
  }

  // At this point, messageObject contains your parsed message as an object.
}
```

That's it! :-)

Comment: Is this still valid or have things changed?

Comment: But I need to identify that this is exception is type of json parse @Golo Roden

Comment: @Pankaj Cheema Just use an if statement inside the catch block.