# Replacement for try/catch in nodejs due to performance overhead

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, performance, try-catch

I am currently using [try/catch to handle JSON.parse errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467044/proper-way-to-catch-exception-from-javascript-method-json-parse). But I have just recently found out after reading some [best practices](http://innofied.com/node-js-best-practices/) that using try/catch on nodejs has some [performance overhead](http://jsperf.com/try-catch-performance-overhead). Is the performance overhead fixed already and is there another way to avoid errors on JSON.parse without using try/catch?

Comment: If you don't wrap `JSON.parse` in `try-catch`, it'll throw an Error into the wilderness - so you'll have to catch it somewhere else. So the technique shown in that answer is correct.

Comment: Related: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/144326/try-catch-in-javascript-isnt-it-a-good-practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The problem with using try/catch constructions instead of callback error functions is that try/catch is NOT able to catch asynchronous events and may leak too much data when the exception is caught.

Best practice is to use try/catch at synchronous events:

```
try
{
  dangerous.function();
}
catch(error);
{
  console.log(error);
}
```

and a callback function for asynchronously fired events:

```
dangerous.function(function(error)
{
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "lead too much data"?

Comment: Like, leaking your entire stack trace from what I've heard.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to avoid try-catch without your own parser.

Try this performance test:
http://jsperf.com/try-catch-performance-overhead

Use Chrome for the test, since NodeJS is just V8.  In my case there was a 41% performance penalty.  However, unless you are going to reading thousands of JSONs per second, I suggest you just use the standard try-catch and make your code readable.

Note that for Firefox, there was virtually no difference between the 3 tests.

Comment: I have stated that url in my question. Thank you though.