# Javascript:handle Unexpected JSON error in express js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I am trying to handle Unexpetced JSON in my express js application via try and catch, so what I am trying to do is

```
try{
  let body = JSON.parse(req.body);
}catch(e){
   res.json({
    error:e
  })
}
```

But the `Unexpected JSON` error not thrown in the `catch block`.

Content-type is `application/json`

Here is the JSON request

```
{
    "userId":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6InNoYW1vbjVAYWNjdWJpdHMuY29tIiwiaWQiOjExNCwiaWF0IjoxNTMxOTgyNDQ0LCJleHAiOjE1MzI1ODcyNDR9.dv1zEnLsmKXbSE4wKbSOdYX3p7v5N5nh9kbz6PA_4TE",
    "readValue":falseuyuyuyu
}
```

`readValue` is malformed

Comment: Could you please check it once more, I hope the error is actually there in `catch` block. What `res.json({
    error:e
  })` suppose to do?

Comment: @jukben its not entering to `catch` block

Comment: The JSON is wrong though, can't have string without quotation marks (unless it's a typo)

Comment: @Baruch  yes JSON is  wrong that i want to catch in error block

Comment: @iambatman Oh, sorry, misunderstood.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling bad JSON.parse() in node safely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29797946/handling-bad-json-parse-in-node-safely)

Comment: Is it possible you're already using a body parser, and so you're attempting to parse a JS object?

Comment: At least in node.js console all works fine. I mean exception trown and passed to `catch` block

Answer (score 0):

you are missing " in the value of 'readValue'. it should be as follow :

```
{
"userId":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6InNoYW1vbjVAYWNjdWJpdHMuY29tIiwiaWQiOjExNCwiaWF0IjoxNTMxOTgyNDQ0LCJleHAiOjE1MzI1ODcyNDR9.dv1zEnLsmKXbSE4wKbSOdYX3p7v5N5nh9kbz6PA_4TE",
"readValue":"falseuyuyuyu"
}
```

Edit: sorry didnt understand the question

Express has its own error handling middleware. in case of error, Express catches the error (in sync code) and handles it, That's why you cant get the error message. What you need to do is to write your own middleware that handles errors in your format. Please go to : https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html and check **Writing error handlers** section.

Comment: Topic starter know that the json is incorrect. The question is "why exception do not thrown?"