# How to get the error message for JSON stringify?

Tags: javascript, json

Suppose I have an object like this

```
var obj = {
"name": "arun"
age
}
```

When I try this, JSON.stringify(obj), I will be recieving an error since the obj is not proper. I want to capture the error shown in the console and show it in the UI.

Is there any callback functionality for the stringify function,so that I can do the above?.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041741/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-string-is-json-in-php

Comment: why don't you use try {} catch?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467044/proper-way-to-catch-exception-from-javascript-method-json-parse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First think there is a `syntax error`, after `"name": "arun"` you need to add `,`

we can't get syntax error programmatically.
after correcting this syntax error, you can check like this

```
try{

   var obj = {
     "name": "arun",
     age
   }

 } catch(e){
   console.log(e);// you can get error here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't going to get an error from JSON.stringify, here.

As soon as you try to make this object, you should get an error.

```
var obj = {
  name: "Arun"  // you're missing a comma
  age //this is valid, as long as `age` exists as a variable above this point, in new browsers
};
```

In all browsers, as soon as you run this part of the script, it's going to throw a SyntaxError, because you're missing the comma.

If you added that comma back in, and `age` did exist above:

```
var age = 32;
var obj = {
  name: "Arun",
  age
};
```

This would now work fine in brand-new browsers, but would again throw a SyntaxError in older browsers.

The legacy-compatible version of that object would look like:

```
var age = 32;
var obj = {
  name: "Arun",
  age: age
};
```

The problem you're having doesn't seem to be that `.stringify` would be breaking.
Based on the object you provided, your statement is broken, period.

Comment: I know the object is faulty, I want to validate that faulty json object and to tell there is an error,at line 3 of the object. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: @ArunMohan It's not a JSON object, if you are declaring it in JavaScript. `var obj = { ];` is not JSON, it's JS. And it will explode before you ever try to put it inside of `stringify`.
If you are downloading it as JSON text, that's a very different thing, and then you wouldn't use `stringify`, you'd use `parse` to turn the string into a JS object. Which do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can try it a way as below:

```
var age = 34;
ar obj = { name: "arun", age }
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```