# JSON.parse() a wrong string

Tags: javascript, json

I have a string that I obtain via a user, so it is not guaranteed to be a correct JSON string format.

This problem may cause the rest of the js code to be stop.

Consider the following example:

```
var a='==wrong string===';
var b=JSON.parse(a);
alert(1); //will not implemented
```

How to avoid this problem?

Comment: Use a `try`-`catch` block around it.

Comment: And implement input validation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467044/proper-way-to-catch-exception-from-javascript-method-json-parse

Comment: @Sirko is right, and then you can right a help function that will return null if the JSON input is not valid..

Comment: user input into a text box?

Answer (score 1):

You can use try catch block:

```js
var a='==wrong string===';
try{
  var b=JSON.parse(a);
 }catch(e){
  console.log(e.message); /*use e.message to get the exact error */
 }
alert(1)
```